# Generate dynamic where clause from xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

i need to send a xml to a store procedure. the xml would look like

```
<NewDataSet>  
<param>  
<SearchField>EmployeeID</SearchField>  
<FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>  
<ConditionData>201</ConditionData>  
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>  
</params>
<param>    
<SearchField>DeptID</SearchField>  
<FilterCondition> = </FilterCondition>  
<ConditionData>AC01</ConditionData>  
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>  
</params>  
<param>    
<SearchField>Dob</SearchField>  
<FilterCondition> <= </FilterCondition>  
<ConditionData>23-MAR-2010</ConditionData>  
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>  
</params>  
</NewDataSet>
```

1. SearchField tag hold the search field name on which search will occur
2. FilterCondition tag will hold the operator i use to search and compare like '%' '<=' '<=' etc
3. ConditionData tag will actual value which we will search
4. MatchCase indicate it will case sensitive or not

i can load the xml and iterate in while loop of cursor and generate a where clause. my question is how can i generate where clause based on field data type.

if the field is string then we always compare like with in '' single quote
if the field is numeric or bit type then we can compare without single quote
if the field is date time then i like to compare like 
`convert(@dob,varchar,112) > '20100101'`

so my question is how to generate where clause based on data type.
i need to fetch the field data type dynamically and accordingly build the where clause.
please share the best idea. thanks

---

i change my xml bit. i include table name for every field. so please tell me what i need to change in this sql to show the data type for every field. to show the data type i need to join with system table. so please do necessary change in ur sql for join with sys table to fetch & show the data type for each field.

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData,   MatchCase,TableName)
SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField, 
    A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator, 
    A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
    A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,
    A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)
```

---

here is my solution.

```
/*
XML DATA SAMPLE
<NewDataSet>
<param>
    <SearchField>EmpID</SearchField>
    <FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
    <ConditionData>201</ConditionData>
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
    <Table>Employee</Table>
</param>
<param>  
    <SearchField>DeptName</SearchField>
    <FilterCondition> = </FilterCondition>
    <ConditionData>AC01</ConditionData>
    <MatchCase>1</MatchCase>
    <Table>Department</Table>
</param>
<param>  
    <SearchField>Dob</SearchField>
    <FilterCondition> >= </FilterCondition>
    <ConditionData>20120104</ConditionData>
    <MatchCase>0</MatchCase>
    <Table>Employee</Table>
</param>
  </NewDataSet>'
  */

  CREATE PROCEDURE GenericSearch
  (
@WhereClause_XML XML,
@LogicalOperator VARCHAR(3)
  )
  AS

 BEGIN

 DECLARE @SearchField VARCHAR(255),
 @Operator VARCHAR(25),
 @ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),
 @MatchCase BIT,
 @TableName VARCHAR(MAX),
 @Validity VARCHAR(100),
 @ColumnType VARCHAR(128),
 @ColumnPrecision INT,
 @ColumnScale INT,
 @ColumnNullable bit,
 @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX)

 DECLARE @tbl_WhereClause AS TABLE 
 (
SearchField VARCHAR(255),
Operator VARCHAR(25),
ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),
MatchCase BIT,
TableName VARCHAR(MAX),
Validity VARCHAR(100),
ColumnType VARCHAR(128),
ColumnPrecision INT,
ColumnScale INT,
ColumnNullable bit
 )


 INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData,   MatchCase,TableName, 
 Validity, ColumnType, ColumnPrecision, ColumnScale, ColumnNullable)

SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField,
A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator,
A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) MatchCase,
A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) TableName,
CASE WHEN t.NAME+c.NAME IS NULL THEN 'invalid' ELSE 'valid' END ,
ty.NAME,
c.PRECISION,
c.Scale,
c.Is_Nullable
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B)
LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON t.name = A.B.value('(Table)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' )
LEFT JOIN sys.COLUMNS c ON T.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID AND c.name =     A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' )
LEFT JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id 

--SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause

SET @WhereClause= 'WHERE 1=1'
DECLARE SearchCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause

OPEN SearchCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor 
INTO @SearchField,  @Operator,@ConditionData,@MatchCase,@TableName,@Validity,@ColumnType,@ColumnPrecision,@Colu    mnScale,@ColumnNullable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF CHARINDEX('INT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) +  @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('NUMERIC', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('BIT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('DECIMAL', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('FLOAT', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('REAL', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('MONEY', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+space(1)+@ConditionData
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('DATE', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + 'CONVERT(varchar,'+@SearchField+',112)' +  space(1)+@Operator+'CONVERT(varchar,'''+@ConditionData+''',112)'
END
ELSE IF CHARINDEX('CHAR', UPPER(@ColumnType)) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + space(1)+ @LogicalOperator + space(1) + @SearchField + space(1)+@Operator+''''+@ConditionData+''''
END 

FETCH NEXT FROM SearchCursor 
INTO @SearchField,  @Operator,@ConditionData,@MatchCase,@TableName,@Validity,@ColumnType,@ColumnPrecision,@ColumnScale,@ColumnNullable
    END

    CLOSE SearchCursor  
    DEALLOCATE SearchCursor 

    SELECT @WhereClause
    END
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in SQL? Wouldn't it be better if you did this in the code that calls the SQL? What language is that code in?

Comment: Hi Thomas apologies for my slow reply. Your solution looks fine to me. I presume this is just a report constructor, so performance building the query isn't really a priority. I won't blab on about the use of cursors etc. The only thing I can spot that may cause you problems is the @ConditionData var you pass into your string, if this contains a string that has a single quote in it, your resulting query will have a syntax error - you may want to escape it.

Comment: thanks for point out good things. so i will replace single quote with double quote in @ConditionData like
REPLACE(@ConditionData, '''', '''''') . any other suggestion

Comment: Aye, when your adding dates to your where clause you're converting the tables date to varchar 112, that's fine, but your converting the @ConditionData to varhcar 112 too, this might not be correct as ConditionData is not a date and the 112 style will have no effect, you should first convert the ConditionData to a date with validation etc (i.e. to catch rouge dates), and then convert the results to a varchar – Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 small things, 1 < & > etc are very illegal in XML markup, if you want to reliably parse it, whatever is generating the XML will need to encode these to the approriate entity reference:

```
&lt;    <    less than
&gt;    >    greater than
&amp;   &    ampersand
&apos;  '    apostrophe
&quot;  "    quotation mark
```

Also, your closing nodes and opening nodes have a typo, for instance <param> is closed by <params> (note the 'S') - assuming this is a typo.

That said, the hardest part is parsing the XML into usefull data that you can use to build your dynamic SQL. You could do this by parsing the XML into a table:

```
DECLARE @tbl_WhereClause AS TABLE (
    SearchField VARCHAR(255),
    Operator VARCHAR(25),
    ConditionData VARCHAR(MAX),
    MatchCase BIT
)

DECLARE @WhereClause_XML XML 
SET @WhereClause_XML = '
<NewDataSet>   
<param>   
<SearchField>EmployeeID</SearchField>   
<FilterCondition> &gt;= </FilterCondition>   
<ConditionData>201</ConditionData>   
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>   
</param> 
<param>     
<SearchField>DeptID</SearchField>   
<FilterCondition> = </FilterCondition>   
<ConditionData>AC01</ConditionData>   
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>   
</param>   
<param>     
<SearchField>Dob</SearchField>   
<FilterCondition> &lt;= </FilterCondition>   
<ConditionData>23-MAR-2010</ConditionData>   
<MatchCase>0</MatchCase>   
</param>   
</NewDataSet>'

INSERT INTO @tbl_WhereClause (SearchField, Operator, ConditionData, MatchCase)
SELECT  A.B.value('(SearchField)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)' ) SearchField, 
        A.B.value('(FilterCondition)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)' ) Operator, 
        A.B.value('(ConditionData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)' ) ConditionData,
        A.B.value('(MatchCase)[1]', 'BIT' ) ConditionData
FROM    @WhereClause_XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/param') A(B) 

SELECT * FROM @tbl_WhereClause
```

Once you have the parsed data, its just an easy case (if not tedious) of iterating through the table and building the where clase string - let me know if you need assistance with that part.

Comment: good idea i will try to generate where clause but '(SearchField)[1]. why it is always (SearchField)[1] and (FilterCondition)[1]

Comment: i edit my post please have a look and answer if possible. thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for ur support which help to initial start. happy new year.here is my latest script from where you can understand how i develop a generic search SP in sql server. i append at the bottom of my post. please have a look & comment if it could develop more better way. thanks

Comment: @Thomas In response to your first comment, the [1] is an array indicator of sorts, say for example the root node had multiple nodes within it of the same name, the [1] just tells SQL to read the first node only – this is a common practice to avoid runtime errors if the xml is arranged in this way - the root node being '/NewDataSet/param' in your case.